# form onSubmit with react-native

Tags: forms, react-native, onsubmit

Sorry if this is a basic question but I just cant seem to find something to replace the 'form' tag in html in my react-native project, so i don't know where to call my "onSubmit" to send my search request, because the 'Form' tag in react-native does not accept the onSubmit event. So what would I use instead??
Here is my code just so you kinda know what it looks like

```
class SearchBar extends Component{
state = { term: '' }

  onFormSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(this.state.term)
  }
 render(){
   return (
     <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
      <Text style=
       {styles.textStyle}>Search For Sick Pics.</Text>

  //so right here is what i dont know what to wrap my Textinput in, like in a react app we would wrap it in the "<form>" tag

        <TextInput 
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        type='text'
        placeholder='Search for Sick pics'
        value = {this.state.term}
        onChange = {event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })}
        />   

  </View>
  )
 }
}
```

this is my main Component

```
     class MainPage extends Component {
      state = { images: [] }

    onSearchSubmit = (term) => {
      axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/search/collections', {
       params: { query: term },
       headers: {
     Authorization: 
     'Client-ID jfkjasdhlkfjskdljfksdjfljasfasdj;fjaskdj'

    }
  }).then((response) => {
   console.log(response)
  })
}

 render() {
   return (
     <View>
         <SearchBar onSubmitEditing={this.onSearchSubmit}/>

     </View>
)
```

}
}

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<TextInput 
  style={styles.inputStyle}
  type='text'
  placeholder='Search for Sick pics'
  value = {this.state.term}
  onChange = {event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value })}
  onSubmitEditing = {() => console.log(this.state.term)}
/>
```

Or you could call your 'onFormSubmit' function aswell

Comment: Would I just call my 'onFormSubmit'                                          like this? onSubmitEditing = {this.onFormSubmit} my main concern is what id call on my main, where i am making my axios request, i updated my original so that you can see how my Mainpage component looks.

Comment: @JoshuaAragon yes, you'd call like this: onSubmitEditing = { (value) => this.onFormSubmit(value) } or onSubmitEditing = { () => this.onFormSubmit(this.state.term) }. I dont know if there's any difference between them

Comment: Yeah... I wasn't able to submit my form still. I put my other main component on my original question if that helps you see a little better what im trying to do